# ERRO LARAVEL: No application encryption key has been specified

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, artisan

Bom dia, estou tentando baixar um template neste link: https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-laravel-57-create-admin-panel-exampleexample.html
 Porém na hora do comando : php artisan key:generate ele gera um erro No application encryption key has been specified, pesquisei e a única solução que encontro é  rodas o cmando php artisan key:generate que é justamente o erro, alguém pode dar um help?

Answer (score 2):

Tente

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Boa tarde, o erro ocorre quando executo justamente o php artisan key:generate , depois mais nehum comando funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Existe o arquivo `.env` no projeto? Caso exista, existe nele a variável `APP_KEY`?

O que o comando `php artisan key:generate` faz é gerar uma chave aleatória para a variável `APP_KEY`.

Caso o comando `php artisan serve` esteja em execução, você precisará reiniciar o servidor.

Comment: Alguém consegue me ajudar com isto?

Answer (score -2):

Você tem que instalar ou atualizar o **composer** antes:

```
composer install
```

ou

```
composer update
```